# How to validate an endpoint returning an image, what particularly should be tested

Tags: java, json, rest, testing, automated-tests

I have a problem with validating an endpoint that is returning PNG image: GET /image/png.
I am using Java + REST Assured framework.
The only tests I can imagine are: to validate a status code of a response of the request and validate the JSON schema.

But I appreciate it if you can advise me on more tests or suggest a source of good practice to do it.

I am a novice in API testing.

Many thanks.

Comment: That really depends on your organization and testing philosophy. There's no one size fits all approach really.
I would test - 1) HTTP status. 2) Header Content Type, 3)If Response Body is empty or not empty 4) Assuming the response is in image/jpeg, check if Header is that type. 
Over the years,I've learned that testing is a skill that takes years to get good at. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will add tests to my suit.